# Oncomplete for if else?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the confusion

I'm trying to run function CCC if the statement is true
and BBB if it isn't

```
if (condition == true) {
    <code if true>
    <code if true>
    <code if true>
    CCC ();
}

else {
    <code if false(else)>
    <code if false(else)>
    <code if false(else)>
    BBB ();
}

function BBB () {

}

function CCC () {

}
```

Comment: "Correctly" depends entirely on what your goal is.

Comment: Do it correctly for what?

Comment: Yes, if you're trying to write gibberish, you're doing an excellent job and it's all done correctly

Comment: I'm unsure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `if (000 == true)`  not very likely mate

Comment: I'm trying to have an if else statement then upon completing the if or else statement - run another function(like an oncomplete statement)

Comment: The code is just an example, what I'm trying to ask is the "oncomplete statement" coded correctly in a way that it will run when the if or else statement is completed and also, after the function has run, run another function upon completion

Comment: The `if` condition is synchronous, it doesn't really "oncomplete", you just stick the code in the different parts etc.

Comment: Adding directly executed code below the if ... else would work. the if ... else is not asynchronous so it will only continue once everything inside is done.
Just add the code directly below it.

Also, everyone saying it's gibberish is right. I'm sorry to say this but i would suggest you would go and learn a bit more theory before attempting actual programming, this code is actually horrible (sorry). Good thing is that you can only improve your skills from now on. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry it's gibberish but it's just an example I'm trying to raise the actual thing runs ok and I'm just checking if I'm doing it right.. Maybe I just phrased it wrongly, I'm trying to run (for instance) function BBB right after the codes if the statement is true and CCC right after the code if the statement is false(else)

Comment: I edited and cleaned up the main, hopefully it's clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just write your code inside of your function?

```
if (condition == true) {
    AAA ();
}

else {
    BBB ();
}

function AAA () {

return <Code you would like to run if true>

}

function BBB () {

return <code you would like to run if false>

}

function ZZZ () {

return <code you would like to run no matter what>


}

ZZZ();
```

Comment: Oh, so I can't run for instance BBB if the statement is true and ZZZ if the statement is false(else)? It will run whatever function that's after it?

Comment: In my example it will run AAA(); if the statement if true. (and it will skip BBB();). Then it the program shall continue and run ZZZ();. Second case if the statement is false it will run BBB(); (and skip AAA();). And then the program shall continue and run ZZZ();

Comment: So true means it will never run BBB, false means it will never run AAA

Comment: Thanks a lot! I misread and thought the functions will run in sequence after the if else ends meaning AAA > BBB > ZZZ always! Last question - is there a way to stop the function from running for instance if it's true, I want it to run AAA only and stop there - I do not want BBB to run unless it's false or ZZZ to run unless I have a call function somewhere

Comment: hmm I am not entirely sure what you mean. Maybe check the other answer aswell, it describes very nicely what will run and when. In my example above BBB will only run if your statement is false. AAA will only run if your statement is true. and ZZZ will always run because i called it after the if-else statement

Comment: I see you changed the question up a bit it's clearer now. Why don't you put the code f what you want to do if false inside your function?

Comment: Yeah am going to do that heh Just realised I made myself confused for no reason when I could have just placed everything inside the if else instead of placing them separately! Sorry for all the trouble :S Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is place the code which should run "on completion" after the if statement

```
if(condition){
   // when true
}else{
   //when false
}

//always
```

Unless your question relates to something asynchronous like a `setTimeout` or an  `xmlhttprequest`. In which case you should look into callbacks / promises

Comment: I could do that too thanks! But can I do a onComplete function inside the if and else separately instead? Or it doesn't make sense to do it that way?

Comment: I don't think I fully understand the question, if you always want to run a function, no matter what the outcome of the if statement, it basically has nothing to do with the if statement. You just need to place the call to the function after it to ensure it is called afterwards